# Issue in Grid layout with scrollview

Tags: android, gridview, scrollview

Consider my scenario, that I am having a relative layout inside it, a grid view containing 6 columns in which i parse and display the json data. It works fine. 
      But when i add more number of rows below, I kept a scroll viewer for that.
The thing is firstly it's displaying the details correctly. But after scrolling, the value changes and does not display it in a proper way. ie, the order of the table values is not exact as it comes from the json. It varies for every scroll.(1st value goes to 3rd place,2nd values goes to 6th columns,etc..) I dont know what is the exact problem. Can you please help me out..

Also I have one more small issue, The heap size of my app is keep on increasing(currently it shows 373M of 742M). I checked for the solutions. Tried adding the code android:largeHeap="true" but this one is not working either.

Advance Thanks for the solution!!

Comment: This could be due to a lot of things, post some code.

Comment: Sure this is my code. `<RelativeLayout 
android:layout_width="match_parent"   android:layout_height="match_parent" ><ScrollView
android:id="@+id/Table"android:layout_width="@dimen/land_Width"
android:layout_height="@dimen/land_Height"
android:visibility="visible" >
<GridView android:id="@+id/gvSummary" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
android:numColumns="2" />(6 text views)
</Scrollview></RelativeLayout>
` where i display the data in the grid view with json value

Comment: Doesn't seem to be anything wrong with the xml layout however do you need the ScrollView? GridView will scroll on itself if items go out of the viewing area.

Comment: Ya i got your point. thanks. Instead of keeping 6 textviews, I kept one spinner and 5 textviews in the gridview. So only i am facing the problem. Is it correct to keep a spinner inside a gridview? Please do help me.

Answer (score 1):

To add Grid view inside a scroll view by using a custom   Gridview  **ExpandableHeightGridView**

please follow the example as below

**ExpandableHeightGridView.java**

```
        public class ExpandableHeightGridView  extends GridView
{
boolean expanded = false;

public ExpandableHeightGridView(Context context)
{
    super(context);
}

public ExpandableHeightGridView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
{
    super(context, attrs);
}

public ExpandableHeightGridView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs,
        int defStyle)
{
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
}

public boolean isExpanded()
{
    return expanded;
}

@Override
public void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec)
{
    // HACK! TAKE THAT ANDROID!
    if (isExpanded())
    {
        // Calculate entire height by providing a very large height hint.
        // But do not use the highest 2 bits of this integer; those are
        // reserved for the MeasureSpec mode.
        int expandSpec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(
                Integer.MAX_VALUE >> 2, MeasureSpec.AT_MOST);
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, expandSpec);

        ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = getLayoutParams();
        params.height = getMeasuredHeight();
    }
    else
    {
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
    }
}

public void setExpanded(boolean expanded)
{
    this.expanded = expanded;
}
}
```

**Xml file**

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:id="@+id/scroll"
android:background="@android:color/white" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@android:color/white" >


     <RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/header"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:background="@android:color/white" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txbar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="9dp"
        android:text="Textview"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textColor="#2c627e"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
</RelativeLayout>


    <yourpackagename of ExpandableHeight.class.ExpandableHeightGridView
        android:id="@+id/gridlist"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/header"
        android:numColumns="2"
        android:scrollbarStyle="outsideOverlay"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:verticalScrollbarPosition="right"
        android:verticalSpacing="10dp" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="120dp"
        android:background="#034E6D"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:id="@+id/view_rl"
        android:layout_below="@+id/gridlist" >

        <!--
         <TextView
        android:id="@+id/newsdata_grid"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/newsdatas"

        android:text="juijb"
        android:maxLines="3"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:textSize="20dp" />
        -->

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/datas_images"
            android:layout_width="60dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:src="@drawable/bike_icon" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/data_grids"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/datas_images"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="VIEWS"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="10dp" />
    </RelativeLayout>
    <View android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="10dp"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:layout_below="@+id/view_rl"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

And in the Activity class

```
    ExpandableHeightGridView gridview=(ExpandableHeightGridView)findViewById(R.id.gridlist);
    gridview.setExpanded(true);
```

This will show a gridview inside a scrollview,Hope this will help you